# SQL одним запросом одинаковые аккаунты

Tags: sql

Как выдернуть все аккаунты с одинаковым ip (`IP`) по логину (`login`). То есть по условию подставляя в запрос один логин, получить аккаунты с таким же ip.

Comment: А структуру таблицы мы сами должны придумать?

Comment: @klopp, Я даже привел названия полей. По-моему больше ничего не надо, Ваш комментарий не уместен. Есть логины, и у некоторых одинаковые ip. Само собой еще поле `id`, которое автоматически присваивается.

Comment: Сколько записей в таблице?

Comment: Записей всего 103 000~. Скорее всего это какое-то ограничение хостинга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

примерно так:

```
select id from accounts where ip in (select ip from accounts where login="логин");
```

Comment: 'Query execution was interrupted'. Повисает намертво, наверняка можно без вложенного селекта. Но не думаю, что проблема в нем. 

         `[SELECT * FROM users WHERE IP IN (SELECT IP FROM users WHERE login LIKE SomeName)]`

Comment: *повисает намертво* — вероятно, очень большая таблица. по поводу *можно без вложенного select-а* — тут, насколько мне известно, одно из двух: или вложенный select, или join. что менее затратно для сервера — зависит, по-моему, как минимум от реализации сервера и от наличия/отсутствия индексов по столбцу `ip`.

Comment: Возможно это блокируется хостингом. Хотя по идеи должны работать оба предложенных варианта. А пока приходится сперва по логину вытаскивать ip, а потом по ip искать схожие аккаунты. Тоже самое, что и предложено, но только в 2 запроса.

Comment: @Fortael, а если добавить `distinct` в обе части запроса?

Comment: `distinct `не помог. Зато помогло сменить `ON` на `LIKE` во вложенном запросе ведь всего один ip.

Comment: @Fortael чтобы ускорить запрос, нужны правильные индексы. Советую использовать `EXPLAIN`, чтобы посмотреть план запроса. Такой запрос должен летать практически на любом сервере.

Answer (score 5):

Как-то так:

```
select distinct a.login from logs a inner join logs b on a.ip = b.ip where b.login = @login
```

Comment: 'Query execution was interrupted'. Та же ошибка и так же долго думает. Изначально именно это в голову и пришло, думал, что можно проще.

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто соединить таблицу саму с собой по IP и исключить записи с тем же IP и логином:

```
SELECT u1.login 
FROM users AS u1
JOIN users AS u2 ON u2.ip = u1.ip AND u2.login <> u1.login 
WHERE ip login = 'SomeName'
```